# R replicate() function doesnt work on Rcpp function

Tags: r, rcpp, replicate

I am having trouble using `replicate()` function in R to generate random numbers with Rcpp function. Consider the following function in R:

```
trial <- function(){rnorm(1)}
replicate(10, trial())
```

It generate 10 random numbers from Gaussian distribution. It works completely fine and produces result like this:

```
 [1]  0.7609912 -0.2949613  1.8684363 -0.3358377 -1.6043926  0.2706250  0.5528813  1.0228125 -0.2419092 -1.4761937
```

However, I have a c++ function `getRan()` that generate a random number from Gaussian distribution. I again used replicate to call the function like this:

```
replicate(10,getRan())
```

It creates a vector of same number like this:

```
> replicate(10,getRan())
 [1] -1.374932 -1.374932 -1.374932 -1.374932 -1.374932 -1.374932 -1.374932 -1.374932 -1.374932 -1.374932
> replicate(10,getRan())
 [1] -0.3273785 -0.3273785 -0.3273785 -0.3273785 -0.3273785 -0.3273785 -0.3273785 -0.3273785 -0.3273785 -0.3273785
> replicate(10,getRan())
 [1] -0.7591953 -0.7591953 -0.7591953 -0.7591953 -0.7591953 -0.7591953 -0.7591953 -0.7591953 -0.7591953 -0.7591953
> replicate(10,getRan())
 [1] -1.698935 -1.698935 -1.698935 -1.698935 -1.698935 -1.698935 -1.698935 -1.698935 -1.698935 -1.698935
```

However, if i call the function multiple times, it works fine:

```
 getRan()
[1] 1.345227
> getRan()
[1] 0.3555393
> getRan()
[1] 1.587241
> getRan()
[1] 0.5313518
```

So what is the problem here? Does the `replicate()` function repeat the same function return from `getRan()` instead of calling `getRan()` multiple times? Is it a bug?

PS: I know I can use `rnorm(n)` to generate n normal random number, however, I want to use the c++ function to do more complex calculations based on generating random numbers

PPS: this is my c++ code:

```
double getRan(){
  unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution (0.0,1.0);
  double epi = distribution(generator);
  return epi;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you check what happens if you do `lapply(1:10, getRan)`? I suspect this is something to do with `replicate` taking an expression, but beyond this I ain't sure...

Comment: Post a *reproducible example*. This is so far just a (possibly well-intentioned, but still useless) rant ...

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that in your C++ a RNG is instantiated with the same seed. For more we need a [mcve].

Comment: @dash2
it produces:

> lapply(1:10,getRan)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (X[[i]])

Comment: @RalfStubner, thanks, i just realised the same thing too, i used time as the seed, so when the function is called with replicate(), the seed is the same, im figuring out how to solve it, here is my C++ code:

`double getRan(){

  unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
  
  std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution (0.0,1.0);
  double epi = distribution(generator);
  return epi;
}`

Comment: It does not make sense to create a new RNG at every call, even if you manage to fix the seeding issues. Why are you not using R‘s RNG as seen in Dirks answer? BTW, time isn‘t the best seed. Better use `std::random_device`.

Comment: Apologies... I meant `lapply(1:10, function (x) getRan())`. Anyway, better experts than me are now talking to you.

Comment: thanks guys, Rcpp::rnorm works well, but somehow my std::random_device doesnt work, it produces same result every time, wanna know why

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counter-example showing that it works just fine:

#### Code

```
trialR <- function() { rnorm(1) }
Rcpp::cppFunction("double trialC() { return R::rnorm(0.0, 1.0); }")
Rcpp::cppFunction("Rcpp::NumericVector trialSugar() { return Rcpp::rnorm(1.0, 0.0, 1.0); }")

set.seed(123); replicate(3, trialR())
set.seed(123); replicate(3, trialC())
set.seed(123); replicate(3, trialSugar())
```

#### Output

Via `Rscript` to ensure fresh session etc pp:

```
edd@rob:/tmp$ Rscript so50543659.R 
[1] -0.560476 -0.230177  1.558708
[1] -0.560476 -0.230177  1.558708
[1] -0.560476 -0.230177  1.558708
edd@rob:/tmp$
```

Answer (score 1):

Dirks answer is correct. You should use R's RNG. If you insist on using a RNG in C++, you can use something like this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <random>

namespace {
  std::default_random_engine generator(std::random_device{}());
  std::normal_distribution<double> distribution (0.0,1.0);  
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double getRan(){
  return distribution(generator);
}

/*** R
replicate(10,getRan())
*/
```

This avoids creating a new instance of `std::default_random_engine` (and `std::normal_distribution`) at every function call. This is important since the properties of a RNG are only guaranteed for repeated draws from one RNG. Not for repeated draws from different RNGs seeded with (hopefully different) seeds.

BTW, on my system your original code does not produce the same number multiple times. If you are having troubles with `std::random_device` and are working on windows, you might be affected by [this mingw bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/338/). In that case seed by time is the better alternative.

Comment: What is the purpose of the namespace declaration if you don't include a name?

Comment: @thc It‘s an anonymous namespace. See for example here for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793334/c-static-vs-namespace-vs-singleton