# Unnamed namespace, templated functions and multiple inclusion

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

(>= c++14)

I'm currently using a namespace *World* as (kind of) a static class.
Here's a little (and dumb) example of what's wrong :

**world.hpp**

```
#pragma once

namespace World {
    namespace {
        template<typename T>
        std::vector<T> components ;
    }

    template<typename T>
    T get(int i) {
        return components<T>[i] ;
    }

    template<typename T>
    void add (T elm) {
        components<T>.push_back(elm) ;
    }
}
```

**layer.hpp**

```
#pragma once

class Layer {
    public:
        float get(int i) ;
        void add(float elm) ;
} ;
```

**layer.cpp**

```
#include "layer.hpp"
#include "world.hpp"

float Layer::get(int i) { return World::get<float>(i) ; }
void Layer::add(float elm) { World::add<float>(elm) ; }
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "world.hpp"
#include "layer.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    Layer layer ;

    for (int i=0 ; i<5 ; ++i) {
        World::add<int>(i) ;
        layer.add(i/5.f) ;
    }

    for (int i=0 ; i<5 ; ++i) {
        std::cout << "get<int>:" << World::get<int>(i) << std::endl ;
        std::cout << "Layer::get:" << layer.get(i) << std::endl ;
        std::cout << "get<float>:" << World::get<float>(i) << std::endl ; // <-- ! SEGFAULT
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

I understand that each time my *world.hpp* file get included in a *.cpp*, it will create a new variable *components* so when I call *layer.get* and *World::get* it will not access the same vector (although this is what I want). I guess it has something to do with **static** or **external** linkage (or am I wrong ?) but I have absolutely no idea how to deal with it. What am I missing ?

[Edit]
What I want is that the vector *components* is unique, so every file that include "world.hpp" refer to the exact same vector.

Comment: Each time `world.hpp` gets included it create a __new__ unnamed namespace nested inside `namespace World` this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Can you explain what you meant "how to deal with it". If you don't want each translation unit to be using an anonymous namespace here, then don't use anonymous namespaces.

Comment: @RichardCritten indeed but since I have templated functions I can't move the unnamed namespace to a .cpp file. 
SamVarshavchik I tried to make my goal a bit clearer.

Comment: Why is there an anonymous namespace at all?

Comment: @RichardCritten to hide the variables from the outside but since it's causing a lot of problems i guess I'll remove it if there's no other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem has not much to do with file inclusion or linkage. `components` is a variable template, not an actual variable. For each type you instantiate it (in your case `float` and `int`), explicitly or implicitly, the compiler will create a variable for you.

So what you basically have:

- with `World.add<int>(...)` in main.cpp you create the variable `World::components<int>` and fill it with values.
- with `layer.add(...)` in main.cpp you call `World::add<float>` in layer.cpp which will create the variable `World::components<float>`

Both are distinct variables, this is how templates work. The same is happening for your function templates in `World`. For each type the templates are instantiated, the compiler will create a new function for you.

**Edit after comments**:

Maybe I still got something wrong, but

- `layer.get(i)` and
- `world::get<float>(i)`

give me the same value, the one added with `layer.add(i/5.f)` so it works like it should, doesn't it?

Both give the values in `World::components<float>` whereas `World::get<int>(i)` gives me the values in `World::components<int>`

Output for the program (after fixing some small errors):

```
get<int>:0
Layer::get:0
get<float>:0
get<int>:1
Layer::get:0.2
get<float>:0.2
get<int>:2
Layer::get:0.4
get<float>:0.4
get<int>:3
Layer::get:0.6
get<float>:0.6
get<int>:4
Layer::get:0.8
get<float>:0.8
```

**Second Edit (digging)**:

So as something should or should not work (and not only sometimes) I started digging. Indeed the compiler creates two instances of `World::components<float>`. After

```
g++ -o prog layer.cpp main.cpp
```

and

```
nm prog | grep components
```

I get

```
0000000000407210 b _ZN5World12_GLOBAL__N_110componentsIfEE
0000000000407230 b _ZN5World12_GLOBAL__N_110componentsIfEE
00000000004071f0 b _ZN5World12_GLOBAL__N_110componentsIiEE
```

which tells me two `components<float>` and one `component<int>` reside in the BSS section of the object file.

Depending of the order of compilation, the program works either as expected or produces a segmentation fault. The order state above works,

```
g++ -o prog main.cpp layer.cpp
```

results in the segmentation fault reported by the op. Without checking the access to all three components in the compiled file, I assume the compilation of main.cpp creates the `float` and `int` version of the vector, the compilation of layer.cpp creates the second `float` version of the vector. The first two are initialized in main.cpp, while the third remains empty - leading to undefined behavior when it is accessed with the `[]` operator later.  It seems if compiled the other way around, the linker resolves every access to `components<float>` to the same instance in the BSS section, so the program is actually running fine, but will probably produces unexpected/undefined behavior under different circumstances (e.g., if the second instance of `components<float>` is accessed somewhere else somehow.

So, a solution is needed. I've change world.hpp to

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>

namespace World {
    template<typename T>
    struct Comp {
        static std::vector<T> components ;
    };  

    template<typename T>
    T get(int i) {
        return Comp<T>::components[i] ;
    }   

    template<typename T>
    void add (T elm) {
        Comp<T>::components.push_back(elm) ;
    }   
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> World::Comp<T>::components;
```

which works, regardless of the order of compilation/linkage.

**Third edit (remarks):**
Btw. I read in your comments below your question that you want to hide `components` from the outside or restrict access to it. If this is your goal you could also do the following:

- Change `World` from namespace to class
- Declare `components` as `private` and `static` member
- Declare your two function as `public` and `static`

I that case you also have to define your private static member the way I did in the example above (last two lines).

Comment: Yes I get this part. But the World::<unnamed>::compenents<float> created by World::add<float> is not the same that the one created by Layer::add(float), which is not the behavior I wanted.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry, I should've compiled your code and tested it before stating the obvious. I'll check.

Comment: Well yeah this looks right ! But it still doesn't work on my computer unless I remove the unnamed namespace .. can you tell me what changes you made and the compiler you're using ?

Comment: I use gcc-Version 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1) (GCC), no additional flags provided. I changed world to World in main.cpp (typo) and added the missing semicolon after the class definition in layer.hpp. I'm currently checking the compiled object files to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I tried again and now it's working, although I don't know what changed ... I'm very very sorry for losing your time. If I find out what changed between before and now, I'll let you know about it. Thanks for the time you spent.

Comment: There actually was an error, I extended my answer after some further digging

Comment: I used a namespace over a "static class" for the reason exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793334/c-static-vs-namespace-vs-singleton) even tho I couldn't apply the exact solution because of my templated functions. Anyway, this works great now.