# Define constant variables in C++ header

Tags: c++, header, constants

A program I am working on has many constants that apply throughout all classes. I want to make one header file "Constants.h", and be able to declare all the relevant constants. Then in my other classes, I can just include `#include "Constants.h`.

I got it to work fine using `#ifndef` ... `#define ...` syntax. However, I would prefer to use the `const int...` form of constants. I'm not quite sure how to though.

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand regarding `const int`?  Post sample code that failed to compile if that's your question?

Comment: For C++ header files you should use .hpp file format to differentiate from C header files which are in .h format.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You could simply define a series of `const ints` in a header file:

```
// Constants.h
#if !defined(MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H)
#define MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H 1

const int a = 100;
const int b = 0x7f;

#endif
```

This works because in C++ a name at namespace scope (including the global namespace) that is explicitly declared const and not explicitly declared extern has internal linkage, so these variables would not cause duplicate symbols when you link together translation units. Alternatively you could explicitly declare the constants as static.

```
static const int a = 100;
static const int b = 0x7f;
```

This is more compatible with C and more readable for people that may not be familiar with C++ linkage rules.

If all the constants are ints then another method you could use is to declare the identifiers as enums.

```
enum mylib_constants {
    a = 100;
    b = 0x7f;
};
```

All of these methods use only a header and allow the declared names to be used as compile time constants. Using `extern const int` and a separate implementation file prevents the names from being used as compile time constants.

---

Note that the rule that makes certain constants implicitly internal linkage *does* apply to pointers, exactly like constants of other types. The tricky thing though is that marking a pointer as `const` requires syntax a little different that most people use to make variables of other types const. You need to do:

```
int * const ptr;
```

to make a constant pointer, so that the rule will apply to it.

Also note that this is one reason I prefer to consistently put `const` after the type: `int const` instead of `const int`. I also put the `*` next to the variable: i.e. `int *ptr;` instead of `int* ptr;` (compare also [this](https://www.quora.com/Where-should-I-put-the-asterisk-for-pointers-in-C++-Is-it-int*-ptr-int-*-ptr-or-int-*ptr) discussion).

I like to do these sorts of things because they reflect the general case of how C++ really works. The alternatives (`const int`, `int* p`) are just special cased to make some simple things more readable. The problem is that when you step out of those simple cases, the special cased alternatives become actively misleading.

So although the earlier examples show the common usage of `const`, I would actually recommend people write them like this:

```
int const a = 100;
int const b = 0x7f;
```

and

```
static int const a = 100;
static int const b = 0x7f;
```

Comment: Your rule with implicit static linkage doesn't work with pointers

Comment: @yanpas It does, however you have to make sure you put the `const` in the correct place. Making a pointer `const` requires putting the `const` after the `*`. E.g. `int * const x`. If you just use `const int *x;` then the `const` refers to what the pointer points to and not the pointer itself.

Comment: It gets a bit cleaner in C++17; see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541011/616460).

Comment: How to understand **Using extern const int and a separate implementation file prevents the names from being used as compile time constants**?

Comment: @John Look at it from the compiler's point of view. You have a header containing `extern const int foo;` and the value of `foo` is set in an implementation file. When you use `foo` in some other file where you've included the header the compiler can't know the value to use as a compile time constant, because while compiling the source file using `foo` the compiler has no idea about the file where `foo`'s is set. This is due to C++'s "separate compilation" model. You could even have different implementation files that set `foo` differently and change the program based on which one you link.

Answer (score 34):

I like the **namespace** better for this kind of purpose.

Option 1 :

```
#ifndef MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H
#define MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H

//  File Name : LibConstants.hpp    Purpose : Global Constants for Lib Utils
namespace LibConstants
{
  const int CurlTimeOut = 0xFF;     // Just some example
  ...
}
#endif

// source.cpp
#include <LibConstants.hpp>
int value = LibConstants::CurlTimeOut;
```

Option 2 :

```
#ifndef MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H
#define MYLIB_CONSTANTS_H
//  File Name : LibConstants.hpp    Purpose : Global Constants for Lib Utils
namespace CurlConstants
{
  const int CurlTimeOut = 0xFF;     // Just some example
  ...
}

namespace MySQLConstants
{
  const int DBPoolSize = 0xFF;      // Just some example
  ...
}
#endif



// source.cpp
#include <LibConstants.hpp>
int value = CurlConstants::CurlTimeOut;
int val2  = MySQLConstants::DBPoolSize;
```

And I would never use a Class to hold this type of HardCoded Const variables.

Comment: I like this idea. But, does this mean I have to initialize `value`, `val2` and every other constants? Is there a way to say include the namespace inside the function and use the same constant names as in namespace?

Comment: Also remember to use `const char *  const` for `char *`

Answer (score 32):

**C++17 `inline` variables**

This awesome C++17 feature allow us to:

- conveniently use just a single memory address for each constant
- store it as a `constexpr`: [How to declare constexpr extern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208685/how-to-declare-constexpr-extern)
- do it in a single line from one header

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>

#include "notmain.hpp"

int main() {
    // Both files see the same memory address.
    assert(&notmain_i == notmain_func());
    assert(notmain_i == 42);
}
```

notmain.hpp

```
#ifndef NOTMAIN_HPP
#define NOTMAIN_HPP

inline constexpr int notmain_i = 42;

const int* notmain_func();

#endif
```

notmain.cpp

```
#include "notmain.hpp"

const int* notmain_func() {
    return &notmain_i;
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -c -o notmain.o -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic notmain.cpp
g++ -c -o main.o -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.cpp
g++ -o main -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic main.o notmain.o
./main
```

[GitHub upstream](https://github.com/cirosantilli/cpp-cheat/tree/085c4b22b1b290a6d033a44958d05054e7e303c7/cpp/inline_variable).

See also: [How do inline variables work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38043442/how-do-inline-variables-work)

**C++ standard on inline variables**

The C++ standard guarantees that the addresses will be the same. [C++17 N4659 standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4659.pdf) 
10.1.6 "The inline specifier":

> 6 An inline function or variable with external linkage shall have the same address in all translation units.

cppreference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline explains that if `static` is not given, then it has external linkage.

**Inline variable implementation**

We can observe how it is implemented with:

```
nm main.o notmain.o
```

which contains:

```
main.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U _Z12notmain_funcv
0000000000000028 r _ZZ4mainE19__PRETTY_FUNCTION__
                 U __assert_fail
0000000000000000 T main
0000000000000000 u notmain_i

notmain.o:
0000000000000000 T _Z12notmain_funcv
0000000000000000 u notmain_i
```

and `man nm` says about `u`:

> "u" The symbol is a unique global symbol.  This is a GNU extension to the standard set of ELF symbol bindings.  For such a symbol the dynamic linker will make sure that in the entire process
>                  there is just one symbol with this name and type in use.

so we see that there is a dedicated ELF extension for this.

**C++17 standard draft on "global" `const` implies `static`**

This is the quote for what was mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043198/895245

[C++17 n4659 standard draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4659.pdf) 6.5 "Program and linkage":

> 3
>   A name having namespace scope (6.3.6) has internal linkage if it is the name of
>
> - (3.1) — a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared static; or,
> - (3.2) — a non-inline variable of non-volatile const-qualified type that is neither explicitly declared extern nor
>     previously declared to have external linkage; or
> - (3.3) — a data member of an anonymous union.

"namespace" scope is what we colloquially often refer to as "global".

Annex C (informative) Compatibility, C.1.2
 Clause 6: "basic concepts" gives the rationale why this was changed from C:

> 6.5 [also 10.1.7]
>
> Change: A name of file scope that is explicitly declared const, and not explicitly declared extern, has
>   internal linkage, while in C it would have external linkage.
>
> Rationale: Because const objects may be used as values during translation in C++, this feature urges
>   programmers to provide an explicit initializer for each const object. This feature allows the user to put
>   const objects in source files that are included in more than one translation unit.
>
> Effect on original feature: Change to semantics of well-defined feature.
>
> Difficulty of converting: Semantic transformation.
>
> How widely used: Seldom.

See also: [Why does const imply internal linkage in C++, when it doesn't in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c)

Tested in GCC 7.4.0, Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 29):

You generally shouldn't use e.g. `const int` in a header file, if it's included in several source files. That is because then the variables will be defined once per source file (translation units technically speaking) because [global `const` variables are implicitly static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c), taking up more memory than required.

You should instead have a special source file, `Constants.cpp` that actually defines the variables, and then have the variables declared as `extern` in the header file.

Something like this header file:

```
// Protect against multiple inclusions in the same source file
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

extern const int CONSTANT_1;

#endif
```

And this in a source file:

```
const int CONSTANT_1 = 123;
```

Comment: @arasmussen Not if you want to use only a single header file. See my revised answer.

Comment: It would be better to initialise it in the header, so it can be used as a compile-time constant.

Comment: Also, you *can* use `const int` in a header file, since `const` variables have internal linkage by default. Whether you'd want that, rather than a single instance, is another question; usually, it makes little difference as long as the value is available in the header.

Comment: This is the correct answer, and should be marked so.

Comment: C++17 inline variables are an even more awesome way to achieve this for those that can use that version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53541011/895245

Comment: Shouldn't the keyword extern be used even in the source file, as global const has static linkage by default?

Comment: @Jamāl Unless there's a previous declaration that forces it to have external linkage, like including the header file containing the `extern` declaration.

Comment: So it must be prefixed by extern if the value is shared among multiple files right? For instance if there's another source file that includes the Constants.h. What I'm really trying to ask is if there's any use to not using the extern keyword in the source file.

Comment: @Jamāl, Some programmer dude is saying that if the source file with the definition is going to include the header which contains the extern declaration then it is not necessary to add the extern keyword to the definition. In case, the source file doesn't include that header file, then, yes, extern keyword must be added to the definition also.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than making a bunch of global variables, you might consider creating a class that has a bunch of public static constants. It's still global, but this way it's wrapped in a class so you know where the constant is coming from and that it's supposed to be a constant.

Constants.h

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

class GlobalConstants {
  public:
    static const int myConstant;
    static const int myOtherConstant;
};

#endif
```

Constants.cpp

```
#include "Constants.h"

const int GlobalConstants::myConstant = 1;
const int GlobalConstants::myOtherConstant = 3;
```

Then you can use this like so:

```
#include "Constants.h"

void foo() {
  int foo = GlobalConstants::myConstant;
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a class to emulate a namespace, when you could just use a namespace?

Comment: At least maybe it would make sense with a struct in C

Answer (score 0):

It seems that bames53's answer can be extended to defining integer and non-integer constant values in namespace and class *declarations* even if they get included in multiple source files.  It is not necessary to put the declarations in a header file but the definitions in a source file.  The following example works for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, for z/OS V2.2 XL C/C++ on OS/390, and for g++ (GCC) 8.1.1 20180502 on GNU/Linux 4.16.14 (Fedora 28).  Note that the constants are declared/defined in only a single header file that gets included in multiple source files.

In foo.cc:

```
#include <cstdio>               // for puts

#include "messages.hh"
#include "bar.hh"
#include "zoo.hh"

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  puts("Hello!");
  bar();
  zoo();
  puts(Message::third);
  return 0;
}
```

In messages.hh:

```
#ifndef MESSAGES_HH
#define MESSAGES_HH

namespace Message {
  char const * const first = "Yes, this is the first message!";
  char const * const second = "This is the second message.";
  char const * const third = "Message #3.";
};

#endif
```

In bar.cc:

```
#include "messages.hh"
#include <cstdio>

void bar(void)
{
  puts("Wow!");
  printf("bar: %s\n", Message::first);
}
```

In zoo.cc:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "messages.hh"

void zoo(void)
{
  printf("zoo: %s\n", Message::second);
}
```

In bar.hh:

```
#ifndef BAR_HH
#define BAR_HH

#include "messages.hh"

void bar(void);

#endif
```

In zoo.hh:

```
#ifndef ZOO_HH
#define ZOO_HH

#include "messages.hh"

void zoo(void);

#endif
```

This yields the following output:

```
Hello!
Wow!
bar: Yes, this is the first message!
zoo: This is the second message.
Message #3.
```

The data type `char const * const` means a constant pointer to an array of constant characters.  The first `const` is needed because (according to g++) "ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'".  The second `const` is needed to avoid link errors due to multiple definitions of the (then insufficiently constant) constants.  Your compiler might not complain if you omit one or both of the `const`s, but then the source code is less portable.