# extern "C" with const

Tags: c++, c

We have a piece of C-code in our system which contains a few arrays like this with global access:

source.h

```
extern const int magic[5];
```

source.c:

```
const int magic[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Somebody decided it would be a good idea to change this to C++ and so the above ended up in an `extern "C"` block:

source.h:

```
extern "C" { 
    const int magic[5]; 
}
```

source.cc:

```
extern "C" {
    const int magic[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

This compiled without a squeak with gcc -Wall

It wasn't until someone tried to use that array that we discovered the problem. using `const` inside an `extern "C"` causes no external symbol to be generated at all. This happens with gcc, sun workshop and ibm's compiler.

I'm somewhat at a loss as to whether or not this is expected behaviour, given that gcc doesn't warn you that you're doing something odd.

So is this behaviour for this specified by the standard, or is it a rather pervasive bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`const` variables have internal linkage (as if declared `static`) unless you use `extern` to specify external linkage. You'll need external linkage if you want to define it in one source file and access it from others.

That's in addition to using `extern "C"` to specify the language linkage.

```
extern "C" { 
    extern const int magic[5]; 
}
```

Your C declaration correctly specified external linkage; but you removed it when you changed to C++.

Comment: And yes, this behavior is specified in the standard. One place where it gets used in C++: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12043198/365496

Comment: To be fair nothing was "removed" in the source file; only in the header did `extern` vanish.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Indeed. But that was enough to break the linkage.

Comment: I agree with your assessment, just not the implication in your final paragraph :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I don't follow. The `extern` was (correctly) present in the C declaration but (incorrectly) missing from the C++ declaration. It was removed when it was changed to C++, as I said.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Oh, yeah, I suppose. I was talking about the definition but I guess that doesn't matter if your translation unit is now referencing a different, undefined, internally-linked array thanks to shenanigans in the header. Carry on.